# How to create mega dropdown menu dynamically using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to create mega drop down menu dynamically. I have created code but not able to display like this: http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/819_megamenu/demo/index.html

I have studied other code but not helping me.

Below is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, label, link, parent FROM menu ORDER BY parent, sort, label");

//Create a multidimensional array to conatin a list of items and parents
$menu = array(
    'items' => array(),
    'parents' => array()
);

//Builds the array lists with data from the menu table
while($items = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //Creates entry into items array with current menu item id ie. $menu['items'][1]
    $menu['items'][$items['id']] = $items;

    //Creates entry into parents array. Parents array contains a list of all items with children
    $menu['parents'][$items['parent']][] = $items['id'];
}
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($menu);

//Menu builder function, parentId 0 is the root
function buildMenu($parent, $menu) {
    $html = "";

    if(isset($menu['parents'][$parent])) {
        $html .= "<ul id='mega-menu-9' class='mega-menu'>";

        foreach($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId) {
            if(!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId])) {
                $html .= "<li><a href='Javascript: void(0);' class='arrow'><span><i class='fa fa-home'></i></span>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['label']."</a><li>";
            }

            if(isset($menu['parents'][$itemId])) {
                $html .= "<li><a href='Javascript: void(0);' class='arrow'><span><i class='fa fa-home'></i></span>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['label']."</a>";
                $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menu);
                $html .= "</li>";
            }
        }

        $html .= "</ul> \n";
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: So what is exactly you question and problem? do you have any issues with your code?

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes it does not create menu like mega drop down the url I provided, I need to create it exactly as given URL, multi column and multi level mega drop down menu

Comment: Try to add relevant classes to relevant elements same as the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge amount of examples in the internet. [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/) is a nice step-by-step explanation of how to build a menu like the one that you want.

I also recommend you to look for [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=dropdown%20menu) as there are a lot of working solutions there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I need to make it dynamically with php and mysql. I have a table that saves all menus and their parents but not getting it print like mega menu using recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me :)

```
    $Testresult = mysql_query("select id,anchordescription,RootMenu,link from MenuTable");
$menu = array(
    'menus' => array(),
    'parent_menus' => array()
);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Testresult))
{
    $menu['menus'][$row['id']] = $row;
    $menu['parent_menus'][$row['RootMenu']][] = $row['id'];
}

function buildMenu($parent, $menu)
{
    $html = "";

    if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$parent]))
    {
        $html .= "<ul id='ulNav'>";
        foreach ($menu['parent_menus'][$parent] as $menu_id)
        {
            if (!isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id]))
            {
                $html .= "<li><a href='" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['link'] . "'>" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['anchordescription'] . "</a></li>";
            }
            if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id]))
            {
                $html .= "<li><a href='" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['link'] . "'>" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['anchordescription'] . "</a>";
                $html .= buildMenu($menu_id, $menu);
                $html .= "</li>";
            }
        }
        $html .= "</ul>";
    }

    return $html;
}
```